# angular ngrx store Parameterized memoized selectors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I read this article https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

And not found how to adapt to pass a params into my selectors

I tried pass a props object into my component to the selector.

[EDITED] answer with @Julius Dzidzevičius solution.

in component

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectors.getPreferences, 'myProps'))
```

in AppState

```
const rootSelectors = {
  layout: (state: AppState) => _.get(state, 'layout'),
}

export interface Selectors {
  getPreferences: MemoizedSelectorWithProps<AppState, string, Preference[]>;
}

export const selectors: Selectors = {
  getPreferences: createSelector(
      rootSelectors.layout,
      (state: LayoutState, props: string) 
=> layoutSelectors.preferences(state, props)) 
};
```

in state

```
export const layoutSelectors = {
  preferences: (state: LayoutState, props: string) => {
    return state.filter(item => item.name === props)
  },
};
```

If someone could tell me just how to adapt correctly this parameter. from component to selector through the memoized Selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memoized selector parameters are held under `props` property. Here:

```
(counter) // should be somewhere else but don't know how :(
=> layoutSelectors.preferences(counter))
```

`counter` is a value that comes from `rootSelectors.layout`. Can't say whats behind it or what is your goal here, but to access props in selector:

```
(counter, props) => layoutSelectors.preferences(props.counter))
```

Comment: Hello i edited my issue with your solution.    thanks for helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```js
export const getUserById = (userId: string) => createSelector(
    getUserList,
    idList => IdList.filter(id => id === userId)
);
```

Please let me know if you still have problem